# Active Directory - User Logon name uniqueness rules

Tags: active-directory

As far as I know that the UPN name should be unique within the Active Directory forest
and user logon name should be unique within the domain (also the pre-windows 2000 sam name should be unique within the domain) , But I was reviewing one of Microsoft training and certificate courses and found the following:

> User logon names for domain user accounts must be unique in Active
> Directory.

I tried creating user with the same logon name on different domains through the forest and there was no problem at all , so how is that possible ?

I even tried creating AD forest on older versions of MS windows Server such as 2003 and even 2000 and also no problem at all .

what did they mean by "domain user accounts must be unique in Active
Directory"? the whole directory or a logical container within the directory such as domain ?

Update:
when i say user logon name this is what i mean:
[image]
Regards

Comment: UPN is not the same attribute as sAMAccountName, so you could have the same sAMAccountName (but different UPNs) in different domains. (Or did I not understand the question?)

Comment: the question  is,  the logon name must be unique in the domain where the user created  or in active directory as a whole ? 
another thing what did you mean by sAMAccountName  , the pre-windows 2000 name ?

Comment: sAMAccountName is labeled in the GUI as "Pre-Windows 2000 account name." That name must be unique in a domain. The UPN will differ between domains. So you could have two accounts in two different domains with the same sAMAccountName but different UPNs (because they are in different domains). So I am not sure I am understanding what's provoking the question. Maybe update your question with an example?

Comment: thanks for the reply , question updated with a image to show what i mean. does the user logon name in the image unique through the forest or just the domain where it was created ?!

Comment: The portion of userPrincipalName to the left of the `@` symbol must be unique per suffix (the name to the right of the `@` symbol). Does that answer it?

Comment: Or, alternatively: The red box you drew in your screen shot is not the entire userPrinicpalName attribute. You have to consider both parts (the name to the left of the `@` and the name to the right of it). They are only separated for convenience in the GUI--in AD, both boxes together form the full userPrincipalName attribute.

Comment: thanks a lot , this answer it all

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is rather old and was answered in the comments, I'd like to make a small addition to it since I just came here via Google.

Microsoft has a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties) which explains all these things, for the user logon name they state:

> The `userPrincipalName` attribute is the logon name for the user. The
> attribute consists of a user principal name (UPN), which is the most
> common logon name for Windows users. Users typically use their UPN to
> log on to a domain. This attribute is an indexed string that is
> single-valued.
>
> A UPN is an Internet-style login name for a user based on the Internet
> standard RFC 822. The UPN is shorter than a distinguished name and
> easier to remember. By convention, this should map to the user's email
> name. The point of the UPN is to consolidate the email and logon
> namespaces so that the user only needs to remember a single name.
>
> [...]  **A UPN must be unique among all security principal objects
> within a directory forest.**

When querying the Active Directory via LDAP, you'll find the following example values (which is exactly your dialog shown at top):

```
userPrincipalName: mario@maio290.de
sAMAccountName: mario
```

I came here because I was curious of the `sAMAccountName`  - for this the above stated document states the following:

> The `sAMAccountName` attribute is a logon name used to support clients
> and servers from previous version of Windows, such as Windows NT 4.0,
> Windows 95, Windows 98, and LAN Manager. The logon name must be 20 or
> fewer characters **and be unique among all security principal objects
> within the domain**.

One implication of the `sAMAccountName` not being unique in a multi-domain-environment is that queries to the RootDSE with referrals can lead to multiple results. This is something one should keep in mind here.

While it's a good practice that the `sAMAccountName` and user part of the `userPrincipalName` are equal, it's also not a must.